# Where can I find published API documentation for Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure

It looks like Azure DevOps may have APIs similar to Office 365 but I'm not finding them in the documentation and when I called support they don't seem to know what I'm talking about. We are trying to build an integration like we have with o365 using Graph api's. Can anyone point me in the right direction- it seems like Azure DevOps is mostly an on-prem solution and not SaaS at this time.

Comment: Am I correct to say that you are talking about the former Visual Studio Online, and now Azure Devops?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019 ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the former Visual Studio Online, and the current Azure Devops, then you have [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) with the reference to its REST APIs. Also you have the option to use the Client SDKs with one of the programming languages available, to establish the integration.

Answer (score 0):

You might looking for Visual Studio SDK documentation...

> The Visual Studio SDK helps you extend Visual Studio features or
>   integrate new features into Visual Studio. You can distribute your
>   extensions to other users, as well as to the Visual Studio
>   Marketplace. The following are some of the ways in which you can
>   extend Visual Studio

Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/visual-studio-sdk?view=vs-2019